# Confusion with heightForHeaderInSection of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I'm using the following code to get an invisible header for my 
UITableView in order to center my UITableViewCells vertically.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    CGFloat contentHeight = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView]; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; ++j) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];
            contentHeight += [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%f", tableView.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f", contentHeight);
    NSLog(@"%f", (tableView.bounds.size.height - contentHeight) / 2);
    return (tableView.bounds.size.height - contentHeight) / 2;
}
```

However, the result returned by NSLog is so weird

[image]

I did not override tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath and there's only one section. How come contentHeight has negative values and why was the method run multiple times?

Comment: There's no way for us to know why contentHeight is negative without knowing if you've implemented tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and if so, what the code is.

It's running multiple times because you either have multiple sections, or the table is getting reloaded.

Comment: @jn_pdx  I did not override tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath and there's only one section.

Comment: This is very specific to you app and I doubt you will get a useful answer without posting more source, then.  There's just not enough here to go on.

Comment: The default height for each row is probably set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` which probably has the value `-1`. Set a specific default height or implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as needed.

Comment: @rmaddy could you put down your answer below so I can accept it